# Generic functions and ref returns in C# 7.0

Tags: c#, generics, pass-by-reference, c#-7.0

Is it possible to use the ref returns feature in C# 7.0 define a generic function that can do both comparison and update of a field in two instances of an Object?  I am imagining something like this:

```
void UpdateIfChanged<TClass, TField>(TClass c1, TClass c2, Func<TClass, TField> getter)
{
    if (!getter(c1).Equals(getter(c2))
    {
        getter(c1) = getter(c2);
    }
}
```

Example intended usage:

```
Thing thing1 = new Thing(field1: 0, field2: "foo");
Thing thing2 = new Thing(field1: -5, field2: "foo");
UpdateIfChanged(thing1, thing2, (Thing t) => ref t.field1);
UpdateIfChanged(thing1, thing2, (Thing t) => ref t.field2);
```

Is there any way to specify a Func type or any kind of generic type restriction that would make this valid by requiring that getter return a reference? I tried `Func<TClass, ref TField>`, but it doesn't appear to be valid syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't be able to use `Func`, because it doesn't return the result by reference.  You'll need to create a new delegate that uses a ref return:

```
public delegate ref TResult RefReturningFunc<TParameter, TResult>(TParameter param);
```

Then changing your function to use that delegate is enough for it to work:

```
public static void UpdateIfChanged<TClass, TField>(TClass c1, TClass c2, RefReturningFunc<TClass, TField> getter)
{
    if (!getter(c1).Equals(getter(c2)))
    {
        getter(c1) = getter(c2);
    }
}
```

Note that a property cannot be returned by reference.  You could return a *field* by reference, or any other *variable*, but a property is not a variable.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare your own delegate type for it. For example:

```
using System;

public class Thing
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;    
}

public delegate ref TOutput FuncRef<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input);

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thing thing1 = new Thing { field1 = 0, field2 = "foo" };
        Thing thing2 = new Thing { field1 = -5, field2= "foo" };
        UpdateIfChanged(thing1, thing2, (Thing t) => ref t.field1);
        UpdateIfChanged(thing1, thing2, (Thing t) => ref t.field2);
    }

    static void UpdateIfChanged<TInput, TOutput>(TInput c1, TInput c2, FuncRef<TInput, TOutput> getter)
    {
        if (!getter(c1).Equals(getter(c2)))
        {
            getter(c1) = getter(c2);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the use of "field" instead of "property" everywhere.)