# Generic functions and cast ref parameter

Tags: c#, generics, pass-by-reference, c#-7.0

```
public void ResponseHandler<T>( string responseContent, ref Result<T> result)
    where T : IServiceModel
{
    var respModel = responseContent.FromJson<OrderResponse>();
    if (respModel.Status.Equals(_innerConfig.SuccessTradeStatus, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        result.IsSuccess = true;
        result.Data.TradeNo = respModel.Transaction_id;// CAN NOT resolve symbol TradeNo   
    }
   ...
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel:IServiceModel
{
    public string TradeNo  { get; set; }
}
public interface IServiceModel
  {
  }
```

usage : `ServiceProvider.ResponseHandler<MyModel>(responseContent, ref result);`

The problem is I can not get the property `TradeNo`,
I found another thread: [Generic functions and ref returns in C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760265/generic-functions-and-ref-returns-in-c-sharp-7-0) 
But not sure it is the same problem with my code.
Any suggestions?Thanks. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `TradeNo` declared? Could you provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem ourselves, with all the relevant types? (And are you sure this is related to `ref` parameters? It's not clear why this is a `ref` parameter at all, as you're not changing the value of the `result` variable itself.)

Comment: you cannot access the TradeNo property because the `ResponseHandler<T>` doesn't know about the type it is handling

Comment: @NitinSawant any casting approach?

Comment: `MyModel` doesn't implement `IServiceModel` in the code you've shown, so you couldn't even call `ResponseHandler` with a `Result<MyModel>`. Even if it *did* implement `ISerivceModel`, your method claims to be able to handle a result for *any* `IServiceModel` type. Perhaps it should be non-generic? `public void ResponseHandler(string responseContent, Result<MyModel> model)`?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `Data` is of type `T`

```
public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

and only constraint for `T` is `where T : IServiceModel`

If you need to access `TradeNo` you need to limit `T` to `MyModel` or add this property to `IServiceModel`

```
public interface IServiceModel
{
    string TradeNo  { get; set; }
}
```